# Problem in putting string in bytebuffer java

Tags: java, android

when I put a string to byte buffer it adds some unknown chars to it.

here is my code:

```
String request="HELLO";
ByteBuffer buffer=ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
buffer.clear();
buffer.put(request.getBytes());
buffer.flip();
```

when I convert it to the string I get the following result: HELLO��������

The way I convert ByteBuffer to string is below:

```
new String(buffer.array())
```

Comment: You're putting 5 bytes into a 1024-byte buffer and then pulling out the entire buffer (along with its uninitialized extra contents).

Comment: so how should I put 5 bytes of string into  buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the string, you didn't take into account that only some of the bytes in the buffer had valid data. The first 5 bytes contain "hello" encoded in some form, the rest are filled with zeros.

To convert a byte buffer to a string, use the [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class:

```
CharBuffer cb = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer);
String str = cb.toString();
```